# Auto switch Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Hi I now make a site and use Bootstrap4. I create some tabs and want that this tabs switch after some time(3 sec). How I can make this?
This is my tabs.

```
<div class="offers">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-4">
                      <div class="list-group list-group-flush" id="list-tab" role="tablist">
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="list-home-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-home" role="tab" aria-controls="home">tab1</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-profile-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile">tab2</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-messages-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages">tab3</a>
                        <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="list-settings-list" data-toggle="list" href="#list-settings" role="tab" aria-controls="settings">tab4</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                      <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="list-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-home-list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Vero autem atque ipsa eligendi! Eos cum labore reprehenderit animi tenetur unde commodi eligendi, hic fuga, explicabo, error corporis. Quia, esse sit!</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-profile-list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa eius deleniti dignissimos, sit voluptatem officia corporis vero tenetur vitae beatae, voluptatibus vel ipsam. Atque, corrupti nam libero quod aspernatur quae!</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-messages-list">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis beatae quod, maiores ea sequi quae neque quibusdam? Necessitatibus cum, impedit magni id fuga officiis ullam, natus ab laudantium sapiente cumque.</div>
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="list-settings" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list-settings-list">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Error saepe impedit, itaque consectetur reiciendis, veritatis, sunt repellat deleniti reprehenderit quibusdam repudiandae ratione optio veniam doloremque non est amet laboriosam! Tempore?</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept in javascript is to remove the active class and add it to the next tab - some pseudo code (one quick how to)

```
    var tabisactive = 0;

    var navLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("list-group-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {
    navLinks[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  tabisactive = tabisactive + 1;
  if (tabisactive >= navLinks.length) tabisactive = 0;
```

add it to the next tab (I use a var tabisactive to store the tab number)

```
 navLinks[tabisactive].classList.add("active");
```

and then set a timer on the function calling it every x secs

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Please can you describe more about this because I really noob in JavaScript(((((

Comment: What do you mean by more : I remove the "active" class -this is in bootstrap4 responsible to show a tab pane and attach  it to the next tab. Then I start a timer to repeat this for the next tab. If the next tab is not existing (so we are on the last tab) move to the first tab (tabisactive = 0).The (java)script can be embedded with <script> tags to the *.html or be called and loaded as *.js.